# When I get data with ajax I cant Post it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

product.php

```
 function getdata(getdatafrom, resultclass){
    $.get(getdatafrom, function(data) {
        $(resultclass).html(data);
    });
}
getdata('get.php?action=porsiyondurum2&id=<?php echo $urunid; ?>','#porsiyondurum2');
```

get.php

```
$action =  htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['action']));
    if($action=="porsiyondurum2"){
        $id =  htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']));
        $urunporkont = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM porsiyon WHERE urunid='$id'");
                                $urunporkonts = mysql_num_rows($urunporkont);

     while($urunporkontv = mysql_fetch_array($urunporkont)){
          $porid = $urunporkontv['id'];
         $porname = $urunporkontv['name'];
          $porucret = $urunporkontv['ucret'];

          echo '<tr><form  action="post.php?action=porguncelle&id='.$porid.'" method="POST" target="frame'.$porid.'"><td><input name="porname" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="'.$porname.'" value="'.$porname.'"></td><td><div class="input-group">
                                                    <input type="number" name="porucret" class="form-control" min="0" placeholder="'.$porucret.'" value="'.$porucret.'">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">₺</span>
                                                </div></td><td class="text-center"><iframe name="frame'.$porid.'" src="not_submitted_yet.php" ></iframe><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick="test()" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Güncelle</button> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"  ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Sil</button></td></form></tr>';
     }

     echo '<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Porsiyon Adı"></td><td><div class="input-group">
                                                    <input type="number" class="form-control"  min="0" placeholder="Ücret">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">₺</span>
                                                </div></td><td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Yeni Ekle</button></td></tr>';

    }
```

As you can see. I can see get.php codes at product.php. But when I trying to frame post it. It doesnt work. Or I tried ajaxpost it didnt happened also. But when I copy this code to product.php It posts perfectly. How can I do this?

Edited: Guys its not php problem. I just wrote related part on get.php

Comment: You have more in your `get.php` file right, something like `$action = $_GET['action'];` etc ?

Comment: you have to use `$_GET` to retrieve values

Answer (score 1):

`$action` is not defined (per the code you've provided), so your initial condition that the entire `get.php` script relies on, *fails*.

`if($action=="porsiyondurum2"){`

Because it's being passed in a `GET` querystring, you need to handle it in that manner, like your other values being passed:

`if($_GET['action'] == "porsiyondurum2"){`

See how you got the *id* by doing just that: `$_GET['id']`. Same applies for *action*.

**In Addition**

I don't see where you're connecting to your database in `get.php`, either. Is there more to the script than what you've posted here? If so, please add it to your post and I will remove this answer (unless it resolves your problem).

Comment: $action =  htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['action']));

Comment: this code already added but I forgot to write here. Its not php problem. Its a ajax form post problem

Comment: Please add all relevant code to your post, as well as any errors you might be seeing, and what is happening when the script is executing (what *is* happening vs what *should* happen).

Comment: Im getting get.php with ajax. when I submit form its not working. But nothing wrong with codes. Cause when I copy the codes to product.php It submit perfectly..